# JSkype error sending message

Tags: java, api, skype

I'm trying to run the following code but unfortunately facing Error problems

```
package jskypeexample;

// import the JSkype packages
   import net.lamot.java.jskype.general.AbstractMessenger;
   import net.lamot.java.jskype.general.MessageListenerInterface;
   import net.lamot.java.jskype.windows.Messenger;
   import java.lang.Thread;
   import java.lang.Exception;

  /**
   *
   * @author swhite
   */
   public class JSkypeExample implements MessageListenerInterface {

   // create a messenger which we'll use for sending messages
   private AbstractMessenger msgr = null;

   /** Creates a new instance of JSkypeExample */
   public JSkypeExample() {

   msgr = new Messenger();
   msgr.addListener(this);
   msgr.initialize(); 
   try {
     // This number may vary on your system depending on the amount
     // of time required to initialize the msgr.
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     // send the Skype API text command
   msgr.sendMessage("Message seanmwhite Hello from UI Student");
     msgr.sendMessage("SEARCH FRIENDS");
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new JSkypeExample();
   }

   public void onMessageReceived(String str) {
     // This is where you will handle all strings that are returned.
     System.out.println(str);
   }

 }
```

But when I comment the following lines then it runs well.

```
 msgr.initialize(); 
 msgr.sendMessage("Message seanmwhite Hello from UI Student");
 msgr.sendMessage("SEARCH FRIENDS");
```

But I have to send commands to receive the response. Actually I'm using JSkype Api (open source api from java ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your boolean value that your initilaze function is returning to true or catch that execpetion if it is false.